# This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, web

I am Working on Flutter App Both for web and mobile and stuck at the Following Error:

````
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Products(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<ProductsModel>> above this Products Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Products is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List<ProductsModel>>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```


The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Products file:///E:/Flutter%20Projects/flutter_web_firebase_host/lib/screens/home/home.dart:37:63
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 332:7                                                                                  _inheritedElementOf
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 284:30                                                                                 of
packages/flutter_web_firebase_host/screens/databaseScreens/products.dart 10:31                                             build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4569:28                                                                        build
...
====================================================================================================
````

Main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/model/users.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/provider/product_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/services/firestore_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firestoreServise = FirestoreService();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ProductProvider(),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => firestoreServise.getProducts(),
          initialData: [],
        ),
        StreamProvider<Users>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
          initialData: null,
        ),
      ],
/*      child: StreamProvider<Users>.value(
        value: AuthService().user,
        initialData: null*/
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
    // );
  }
```

Product.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/model/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/screens/databaseScreens/edit_product.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Products extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final products = Provider.of<List<ProductsModel>>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Products'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditProduct()));
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: (products != null)
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(products[index].name),
                    trailing: Text(products[index].price.toString()),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditProduct(products[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}
```

Home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/screens/databaseScreens/products.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/shared/drawer.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('logout'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Products()));
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50, 0, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Stock Market',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/graph.jpg",
                      width: 500,
                      height: 600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

product_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/model/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/services/firestore_service.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  String _name;
  double _price;
  String _productId;
  var uuid = Uuid();

  //Geters
  String get name => _name;
  double get price => _price;

//Seters
  changeName(String value) {
    _name = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changePrice(String value) {
    _price = double.parse(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  loadValues(ProductsModel product) {
    _name=product.name;
    _price=product.price;
    _productId=product.productId;
  }



  saveProduct() {
    print(_productId);
    if (_productId == null) {
      var newProduct = ProductsModel(name: name, price: price, productId: uuid.v4());
      firestoreService.saveProduct(newProduct);
    } else {
      //Update
      var updatedProduct =
      ProductsModel(name: name, price: _price, productId: _productId);
      firestoreService.saveProduct(updatedProduct);
    }
  }
}
```

Authservise.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_host/model/users.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  Users _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? Users(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<Users> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential  result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
     User user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential  result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
     User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //sign in with google
  Future<bool> loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if(account == null )
        return false;
      UserCredential res = await _auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: (await account.authentication).idToken,
        accessToken: (await account.authentication).accessToken,
      ));
      if(res.user == null)
        return false;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      print("Error logging with google");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically my app is connect to firebase both for web app and android app. Also i send data to firestore from my app but when i click the add button to go to textfield to send data it give the error as i mention it in start. I am using multiprovider as you can see my main.dart code

Is There anything I missing. I need Help.

Answer (score 4):

the way to fix this is to put MultiProvider as parent of myApp in your main like this

```
    runApp(
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ProductProvider(),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => firestoreServise.getProducts(),
          initialData: [],
        ),
        StreamProvider<Users>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
          initialData: null,
        ),
      ],
child:MyApp(
      ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I try it but Its not Working still getting the Same error.

Comment: In my case it worked like a charm, thanks.